# React Native: how to get unsigned apk?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, unsigned

I tried to get an unsigned APK. I used the following steps

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

and then

```
cd android
assembleDebug
```

and  I also tried

```
cd android
assembleRelease
```

I get two APKs. the debug APK get an error that the developement server is not found. 
So I used the release APK to install on my device but that doesnt work either. I can install the app.
I dont need an sigend APK just a usignes APK for testings.

EDIT: forgot to say that I'm working on Windows.

Comment: Do you have .keystore file in android/app/ directory? 
Did you use cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease?

Comment: No I dont have one int the "android/app" directory. But why do I need some, if I dont want a signed apk?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need one, just getting clarification. Did you use cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease ?

Comment: I used the code above. So first the react-native bundle.... and then cd android and in the android directory I did assembleRelease. An APK was build, but I cant install this on my phone although I gave the permission to install from unknown resources